# Regex to allow space after one word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have used a regex which allows the user to enter alphanumeric values like

**ABC123**, **xyz321**

but now what I want is with these characters, it is not allowing me to enter space between some characters.

**abc test7**, **123test abc4** this should also work

**Working Example:-**

123abc test4

A7 organisation.

I dont want like this:-

**1221 121**

below is my code

```
function NumbersWithCharValidation(thisObj) {
        var textBoxvalue = thisObj.value;
        if (textBoxvalue.length == 0 || (isNaN(textBoxvalue) && !textBoxvalue.match(/\W/))) {
        }
        else {
            alert('Numbers and Special characters are not allowed');
            document.getElementById('txtNameOfFirm').focus();
        }
    }
```

kindly suggest what is wrong here

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: it is accepting `232 2323`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: it is still taking numbers after spaces  like `221 23323`

Comment: do you want it to work with ',' or '.' at the end?
you've specified a '.' after A7 organisation.

Comment: @TaranJ: i dont want `.` but the regex provided by **anubhava** is working fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!\d+\b)\w+(?: \w+)*$/
```

This regex will spaced between words. Negative lookahead `(?!\d+\b)` is to prevent the case of `123 456` as valid input.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zB8jU3/1)

Comment: let me try and check, will it come under double quotes `"your regex"` ?

Comment: No it is not accepting `121 345` as yo can [see this in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zB8jU3/2) Make sure to use `g` and `m` flags

Comment: No sir, I tried like this, `if (textBoxvalue.length == 0 || (isNaN(textBoxvalue) && !textBoxvalue.match("/^(?!\d+\b)\w+(?: \w+)*$/"))) {
            }` but  i am able to insert `12121 2323`

Comment: That is wrong. It should be `!textBoxvalue.match(/^(?!\d+\b)\w+(?: \w+)*$/)))` (no quotes around regex)

Comment: its going other way round, it is not allowing me to add `abc tes` but allowing me `12 12`

Comment: Because you have `!` before. It should be like this `if (/^(?!\d+\b)\w+(?: \w+)*$/.test(textBoxvalue)) { // valid } else { //invalid }`

Comment: yup now it is working as required, let me test and confirm for some time. Then i will accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

use this regEx to match ur input:

```
(?!\d+\b)\w+\s*
```